# run automated queries at predefined time

Tags: php, mysql, performance

just wondering what's the best way to solve this issue:
i have a column in my table called end_time.
for every row, i have to check when this end_time is reached and modify a flag.
i'm thinking of writing an app (using php) that checks every minute if my current time is equal to one or more of the available end_Time in the database, then modify the flag.
is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

newer versions of mysql have an event scheduler.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html